# command npm install swiper failed - code 255

Tags: node.js, npm, swiper.js

When I try to run `npm install` swiper throws an error. I tried to install swiper locally and globally with:

```
npm install swiper
npm install -g swiper
```

I successfully installed it globally. But when I try to install it again the error is the same.

Here is the error:

```
npm ERR! code 255
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Emir\Desktop\Project\portal\node_modules\swiper
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c 
C:\Users\Emir\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-cab5f01a.cmd
npm ERR! "Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:"
npm ERR! The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Node version? Swiper Version. NPM version? `"swiper": "^8.4.3"`. No known issue related to this. Also check other packages. https://careerkarma.com/blog/npm-command-not-found/

Answer (score 6):

Hey you are probably a windows user like me.

I had this error fixed it by setting an environment variable

There is a problem with the swiper postinstall file

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/copy/postinstall.js

you need to bypass this

```
function isBannerRequired() {
  return !(ADBLOCK || CI || DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE || SILENT || OPEN_SOURCE_CONTRIBUTOR);
}
```

so inside vs code open a terminal and write to bypass the equality test

```
 $env:OPEN_SOURCE_CONTRIBUTOR="true"
```

then try npm install

Comment: I'm on Windows but this solution is not working, same error happens even after the variable is set

Answer (score 1):

Remove Swiper From Your package.json file and also delete node_modules and package-lock.json file.

After that **npm install --force** and **npm install swiper --force** individually.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the swiper in the project folder and it worked!